# Using regex to extract a string including a space between other strings and whitespace

Tags: regex, ansible, regex-group

I have the following output from my wireless controller and also the regex statement below. I am trying to parse out the various values using regex named capturing groups. The space in the 'Global/whatever Lab/Lab01' value is throwing everything after that value off. Is there a way to repalce the \S+ after the  group to capture the whole value of 'Global/whatever Lab/Lab01'? Thank you.

```
Number of APs: 2\nAP Name                            Slots    AP Model  Ethernet MAC    Radio MAC       Location                          Country     IP Address                                 State         \nAPAC4A.56BE.18A0                     2      9120AXI   ac4a.56be.18a0  045f.b91a.0a40  Global/whatever Lab/Lab01  US          2.2.2.2                                Registered    \nAPHAV-LAB-TEST-01                    2      9120AXI   ac4a.56be.8cd4  045f.b91d.4ce0  default location                  US          1.1.1.1                               Registered
```

```
(?P<ap_name>\S+)\s+(?P<slots>\d+)\s+(?P<model_number>\S+)\s+(?P<ether_mac>\S+)\s+(?P<radio_mac>\S+)\s+(?P<location>\S+)\s(?P<country>\S+)\s+(?P<ip_address>\S+)?\s+(?P<state>\S+)
```

Comment: You can use this: `/\s{2,}/g` and replace with a single space leaving `Number of APs: 2\nAP Name Slots AP Model Ethernet MAC Radio MAC Location Country IP Address State \nAPAC4A.56BE.18A0 2 9120AXI ac4a.56be.18a0 045f.b91a.0a40 Global/whatever Lab/Lab01 US 2.2.2.2 `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to match a multi-word field value, make sure you can describe the format of the field(s) next to it. Once you know the rules, you can match the "unknown" field with a mere `.*?` pattern.

See an example solution:

```
(?P<ap_name>\S+)\s+(?P<slots>\d+)\s+(?P<model_number>\S+)\s+(?P<ether_mac>\S+)\s+(?P<radio_mac>\S+)\s+(?P<location>.*?)\s+(?P<country>[A-Z]{2,})(?:\s+(?P<ip_address>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}))?\s+(?P<state>\S+)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/1J7Jjj/3).

Now, the `location` group pattern is `(?P<location>.*?)` and it matches any char, 0 or more occurrences but as few times as possible, other than line break chars, and it is possible here since the next group pattern, `country` group, is now `(?P<country>[A-Z]{2,})` and matches any substring of two or more uppercase ASCII letters.

Note I also "spelled out" the `ip_address` group pattern and made the whole part with initial whitespaces optional, `(?:\s+(?P<ip_address>\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3}))?`.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try doing something similar to replacing `\S+` with `[\S ]+`
I don't know if there's anything like an escape code you can use to represent the space between the `[]`